Не работает websocket в связке Vuejs+Laravel 11
Недавно начала изучать веб сокеты и все, что к нему прилагается в Laravel 11. Бэкенд реализовал собственно на ларе, добавил нужный эвент, обновил конфигурацию pusher и тд , фронтенд отдельным проектом на vueJs, где попросил ChatGPT накидать простой компонент экран, на котором бы выводились новые записи из бэкенда и сообщения в консоль, добавленные через postman.Соединение с вебсокетом на фронте есть, но новые сообщения никак не транслируются на клиент.
Ниже код на Laravel
Сам эвент
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Message;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            'chat',
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => $this->message];
    }
}


Роут в routes/channels
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

Broadcast::channel('chat', function () {
    return true;
});

Сервис контейнер в котором вызывается эвент

namespace App\Services\Message;

use App\Models\Message;
use App\Events\MessageSent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Http\Requests\MessageValidation;
use App\Interfaces\Message\MessageServiceInterface;

class MessageService implements MessageServiceInterface
{

    public function index(): object
    {
        $messages = Message::with(["user", "chat"])->get();

        return $messages;
    }

    public function store(MessageValidation $req): Message
    {
        $validationData = $req->validated();
        $newMessage = Message::create($validationData);

        Log::info('Broadcasting message:', ['message' => $newMessage]);
        broadcast(new MessageSent($newMessage))->toOthers();

        return $newMessage;
    }

    public function show(Message $message): Message
    {
        return $message;
    }

    public function update(MessageValidation $req, Message $message): Message
    {
        $validationData = $req->validated();
        $message->update($validationData);

        return $message;
    }

    public function destroy(Message $message): void
    {
        $message->delete();
    }
}

Vuejs компонента
<template>
    <div>
        <ul v-if="!isLoading">
            <li v-for="message in messageStore.messages" :key="message.id">
                <strong>{{ message.user.name }}</strong>: {{ message.message }}
                <span class="date">({{ formatDate(message.created_at) }})</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p v-else>Загрузка...</p> <!-- Индикатор загрузки -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import { useMessageStore } from '../stores/messageStore';
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";

export default {
    setup() {
        const messageStore = useMessageStore();
        const isLoading = ref(true); // Переменная для отслеживания состояния загрузки

        // Подключаемся к Pusher
        window.Pusher = Pusher;
        const echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: "pusher",
            key: "5a0c13e00857a82a2bb6",
            cluster: "eu",
            forceTLS: true,
        });

        echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind('connected', () => {
            console.log('Подключение к Pusher успешно!');
        });

        echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind('disconnected', () => {
            console.log('Подключение к Pusher разорвано.');
        });

        echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind('error', (error) => {
            console.error('Ошибка подключения к Pusher:', error);
        });

        echo.channel("chat")
            .listen("MessageSent", (event) => {
                console.log(event);
                // messageStore.addMessage(event.message); 
            });

        // Загружаем сообщения при монтировании
        onMounted(async () => {
            await messageStore.loadMessages(); // Загружаем сообщения при монтировании компонента
            isLoading.value = false; // Устанавливаем состояние загрузки в false после загрузки
        });

        // Функция для форматирования даты
        const formatDate = (dateString) => {
            const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' };
            return new Date(dateString).toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
        };

        return {
            formatDate,
            messageStore,
            isLoading, // Возвращаем переменную состояния загрузки
        };
    },
};
</script>

Store
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

const API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/messages';

export const useMessageStore = defineStore('messageStore', {
    state:()=>({
        messages:[],
    }),

    getters:{},

    actions:{
         async loadMessages(){
            try {
                const response = await fetch(API_URL);
                if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Failed to fetch messages');
                const data = await response.json();
                this.messages = data.messages; // Используйте .messages, если ваш ответ содержит его
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        },

        addMessage(message){
            this.messages.push(message)
        }
    }

});

vue.config.js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    host: '127.0.0.1', // Указываем хост
    port: 8080, // Укажите порт, на котором работает ваш сервер\
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', // Порт вашего Laravel приложения
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
})


Смог решить эту ошибку добавив "." перед названием эвента в vuejs + очистив кэш в laravel
echo.channel("Chat")
            .listen(".chat.message", e => {
                console.log(e);
                messageStore.addMessage(e);
            });

